# Rest call to delete azure storage queue msg with a '+' character in the popreceipt fails

Tags: azure-storage-queues

### All REST delete calls with a '+' character in the popreceipt fail:

Request URL: `https://myaccnt.queue.core.windows.net/myq/messages/mymsg?popreceipt=AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAW3Dka+IB1gE=`
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 400 Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.

### BUT

### All REST delete calls without a '+' character in the popreceipt succeed:

Request URL: `https://myaccnt.queue.core.windows.net/myq/messages/mymsg?popreceipt=AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAA3eUEweIB1gE=`
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 204 No Content

Answer (score 2):

Since `+` character is a reserved URL character, you will need to URL encode it. Instead of `AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAW3Dka+IB1gE=`, try passing `AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAW3Dka%2BIB1gE%3D` in the query string.

When you pass `AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAW3Dka+IB1gE=` in the query string, it is received as `AgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAW3Dka IB1gE=` (`+` sign gets converted to a space) and that causes pop receipt to mismatch which results in error.